# c# - call a specific method when signatures are the same

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure exactly how to call this situation, but here it is:

I have 2 methods with different types, but from the "outside" they have the same signature. And when calling the method, I would like to invoke a specific method instead of the other - here is what I have:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public async Task<Response<T>> MyMethod<T>(string name, T myObj)
    {
        // some code here
    }

    public async Task<Response<T>> MyMethod<T>(string name, string myObj)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

For the compiler, the 2 methods above are different and have different signatures. But when calling:

```
var myClass = new SomeClass();
myClass.MyMethod("name", "something");
```

When calling `MyMethod` in the example, what's being called is `MyMethod<T>(string name, T myObj)`, but what I would actually want to call is the second method. Is there a way to make it call a specific signature?

**EDIT:**

I found the if I give in one of the methods a different name to the second variable and then calling the method with the variable name as part of the call it does work, as in the following example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public async Task<Response<T>> MyMethod<T>(string name, T myObj)
    {
        // some code here
    }

    public async Task<Response<T>> MyMethod<T>(string name, string myNewObj)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

```
var myClass = new SomeClass();
myClass.MyMethod<AnyOfMyTypes>("name", myNewObj: "something");
```

While this works, following Jon's response below, does it seem like something that is correct to do? As far as for the method name, I would like to keep it the same, and the other option is to change the signature by adding some dummy `boolean` variable.

Comment: Can you constrain the non-string object types for T? Do they for example implement always the same interface? Then you could use the "where" clause - so if T would implement the IComparable interface for example, you could constrain the class definition public class SomeClass<T> where T : IComparable<T>

Comment: It is important to remember that it should not be enough that the signature is the same, the meaning should also be the same. Here you have one method that has a `<T>`, where that `T` is also the type of a parameter. In the other method, you don't have a `T` as a parameter type. In my mind, these methods do different things, in one case you're accepting any type of parameters in a strongly generic typed manner, in the other you're passing an additional parameter, a type, using `T`. ie. to me the methods read like "one has 2 parameters, generically typed, the other has 3 where one is a type".

Comment: My comment above is not about the compiler or what it should support, it is about the names chosen. Since, to me, the methods read like different operations, they probably shouldn't have the same name. This is an opinion, however, so I'm not going to provide an answer about any of this.

Comment: Also, you should try to avoid asking "Is this the right thing to do?" as this will likely lead to your question getting close votes with "Primarily opinion-based". Leave the question as asking why the compiler didn't want to call the second method with Jons answer, is my advice.

Answer (score 11):

The compiler certainly *can't* call the second method with that calling code, as it wouldn't know what to infer for `T`. If you specify a type argument though, it does call the second method:

```
myClass.MyMethod<string>("name", "something");
```

While that will work, I would *strongly* advise you to change the design if you possibly can. Rename one of the methods. I can reasonably call myself a C# expert, but *I couldn't predict from inspection whether or not that would work*. The overload resolution and type inference details in C# are really complicated, and it's unreasonable to expect every C# developer to know them inside out.

If you can give the methods different names, the code code is likely to be a *lot* simpler to read.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see my edit in above post.

Comment: @developer82: Well you've said you "would like to keep it the same" but provided no reasons for that. It's very hard to make concrete suggestions when we don't know the real method name (which I assume isn't `MyMethod`) but I would really urge you to consider whether you absolutely *have* to keep the same name. What's the benefit of that compared with the significantly-simpler-to-understand code using two different names?

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe the mthod is already widely used and changing the name will require lot of changes :) but it is just a guess

Comment: Maybe for user , keep same name as well , bacause other peple don't know method detail ,if make differernce name user will comfuse how to choose, I just guess:)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: That's why the OP should give more information - so that don't *need* to guess.

Comment: @TimChang: If the two methods did the same thing, it wouldn't matter which one was being called. It sounds like they *do* behave differently, so users *should* have to choose between them - and a name can help make that choice simpler. The idea of "don't force people to think" isn't nearly as compelling IMO as "force people to make choices where you can't make the choice on their behalf, and make that choice as simple to express as possible". That's our explicit design philosophy in Noda Time.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes , I meant from user part of view is a same thing , But if user have some purpose "have to" make chooise , I very agrees make a different method name :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi can you please provide any resources to How C# inokes a method in these scenarios.

Comment: @SanjayIdpuganti: It's all in the C# standard: https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm but the rules can be *really* hard to trace through in complicated scenarios... you definitely don't want developers to have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Following Jon's answer I'd suggest following solution to your problem:

```
private async Task<Response<T>> MethodForString<T>(string str)
{
  // some code...
}
public async Task<Response<T>> Method<T>(T obj)
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    return MethodForString<T>(obj as string);

  // some code...
}
```

Above is just a sample, but idea is simple: just check type of `T` and call appropriate method :)

This way, all your method call will remain exactly the same :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see my edit in above post.

Comment: @developer82 Why you don't want to change method name? Your all calls would remain the same, while call with `string` will be redirected to appropriate method. Using parameter names in invactions will reduce readability. Better choice would be add some dummy variable to change the signature, but still, it is not so readable and obvious for ones, who will use it.

Comment: I don't want to change the method name since the purpose of the method is the same in all cases - I just want to give the calling user more options to work with that specific call that in any case should do the same logic behind the scenes.

Comment: @developer82 Ok, that's why method with changed names should be `private`, so they will be inaccessible from outside anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first method is being called is because you have a generic type of T.
If you pass a string into this then it will hit the first method. It is better design to only have one method. If you want to be able to pass in any type then keep the first method, if you want just a string then keep just the second method. You should only have two methods if both have distinct clear purposes.

This

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public async Task<Response<T>> MyMethod<T>(string name, T myObj)
  {
    // some code here
  }
}
```

Or

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public async Task<Response<T>> MyMethod<T>(string name, string myObj)
  {
    // some code here
  }
}
```

Or

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public async Task<Response<T>> MyMethod<T>(string name, string myObj)
  {
    // some code here
  }
  public async Task<Response<T>> MyMethod<T>(string name, int age, string address)
  {
    // some code here
  }
}
```

Dont put a dummy variable into any of the methods, this will lead to problems debugging and be misleading for other developers.